# Object returned from OQL query in jhat does not match query

Tags: java, jhat

Our team has a Java process running (on a 64-bit server OpenJDK 1.8.0_171-b10) in which some unexplainable things happen regarding the value of (boxed) `Long` objects. We have created a heap dump to analyse with `jhat` and here something really strange occurs.

Having `jhat` running, we issue one of the following OQL queries:

- `select l from java.lang.Long l where l.value.toString().equals("20180919141719600")`
- `select l from java.lang.Long l where l.value == 20180919141719600`

Both result in the same three objects being returned. However, when we inspect the objects, all three have a different value in `value` and neither of those equals `20180919141719600`.

- [Screenshot of OQL query with results of three objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1g0VA.png)
- [Screenshot of details of one of the objects, showing a different value than used in the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BM5eH.png)

This in itself bothers us and is the core of our question.

Additionally, we can make the situation a bit more interesting. It seems as if the running Java code uses the actual values (as we see using `jhat` in the `value` field of the `Long` objects), except in JSON serialisation, because the REST endpoint returns the value `20180919141719600`. This signals that somehow both values are actually in memory (and heap dump) and somehow JSON serialisation (using Jackson) does something different, congruent to what `jhat` does when running OQL queries.

What would be the next step to analyse this situation?

Comment: `20180919141719600` looks a lot like a timestamp (2018-09-19 14:17:19.600). Could you be looking for the value of a `Date` object, e.g. the value `1537366639600`??

Comment: It looks like that, but it actually is a sequence number. The party that used this sequence number initialises their sequence number generator with the current date and time at application startup. So it's not actually a timestamp.